# SQL group 2 rows based on column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
Row ID Name Parent
1   c1 John p1 
2   c2 Dave p2
3   p1 Lex  p3
```

I want to group the rows together that have a child and parent relationship indicated by the ID and Parent Columns for example

the query should return

```
Row ID Name Parent
1   c1 John p1
3   p1 Lex  p3
2   c2 Dave p2
```

Any advice on how to achieve this without adding additional columns?

Comment: Do you really want to display parents _below_ their children?

Comment: Apologies I forgot to say, MS SQL Server

Comment: There is no `p3` defined; how do we know how deep the hierarchy may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working on SQL Server, you have the option of using [recursive CTE SQL query](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx) as I shared the codes below

```
/*
create table hierarchy_data
(
Row int,
ID varchar(2),
Name varchar(20),
Parent varchar(2)
)
insert into hierarchy_data select 1   ,'c1', 'John', 'p1' 
insert into hierarchy_data select 2   ,'c2' ,'Dave' ,'p2'
insert into hierarchy_data select 3   ,'p1' ,'Lex'  ,'p3'
*/
;with cte as (
    select 
        row, 
        id, 
        name, 
        parent,
        row_number() over (order by id) as groupno,
        1 as level
    from hierarchy_data
    where parent not in (
        select id from hierarchy_data
    )

    union all

    select
        h.row,
        h.id,
        h.name,
        h.parent,
        cte.groupno,
        cte.level + 1
    from cte
    inner join hierarchy_data h
        on cte.id = h.parent

)
select *
from cte
order by groupno, level
```

Hierarchy or parent-child relation is built within the CTE expression.
By using the ORDER BY clause you can sort the output as you wish

The output is as

[image]